# How to make moving text bounce off each other instead of overlapping in JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make two words which are divs that move around the page randomly for my website.

However whenever the two words come into contact, I want them to bounce off each other instead of overlapping each other.

What do I need to change and add in my Javascript? I have posted the code of the moving words.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    animateDiv();
    animateDivTwo();
    
});
      
      
      // MOTION 
function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 100;
    var w = $(window).width() - 100;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.motion').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    
    
    $('.motion').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });
    
};

function animateDivTwo(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.designer').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.designer').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDivTwo(this);        
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    
    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed; }
```

```css
 @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Mono&display=swap');
 
 /*MOTION*/
    
        h2{
        font-size: 40px;
        font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
        user-select: none;
    }
  .motion {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
      

}

/*DESIGNER*/
    
    h3{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    user-select: none;
    }
    
  .designer {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 1200px;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        
        
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>


        
        <div class="motion">
        <h2>
        motion
        </h2>
        </div>
        
        <div class="designer">
        <h3>
        designer
        </h3>
        </div>



        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js">
        </script>


        
            
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to avoid overlaps, you can get started with simple `collision detection` function in Javascript called `overlaps` running continuously, it detects the overlapping between motion div and designer div as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    animateDiv();
    animateDivTwo();

    setInterval(function(){
        var $motion = $('.motion');
        var $designer = $('.designer');
        var isOverlap = overlaps($motion[0], $designer[0]);
        if(isOverlap){

            $motion.stop(true);
            $designer.stop(true);
            
            $motion.animate({ top: $motion.offset().top - 20, left: $motion.offset().left - 20 }, 100, function(){
              animateDiv();        
            });

            $designer.animate({ top: $designer.offset().top + 20, left: $designer.offset().left + 20 }, 100, function(){
              animateDivTwo();        
            });
        }
    }, 100);

});

function overlaps(a, b) {
  const rect1 = a.getBoundingClientRect();
  const rect2 = b.getBoundingClientRect();
  const isInHoriztonalBounds =
    rect1.x < rect2.x + rect2.width && rect1.x + rect1.width > rect2.x;
  const isInVerticalBounds =
    rect1.y < rect2.y + rect2.height && rect1.y + rect1.height > rect2.y;
  const isOverlapping = isInHoriztonalBounds && isInVerticalBounds;
  return isOverlapping;
}


// MOTION 
function makeNewPosition(){

    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $(window).height() - 100;
    var w = $(window).width() - 100;

    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

    return [nh,nw];    

}

function animateDiv(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.motion').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);


    $('.motion').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv();        
    });

};

function animateDivTwo(){
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $('.designer').offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

    $('.designer').animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDivTwo(this);        
    });

};

function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

    var speedModifier = 0.1;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed; }
```

```css
h2{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    user-select: none;
}
.motion {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50px;
}

h3{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Mono', monospace;
    user-select: none;
}

.designer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 1200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="motion">
<h2>
motion
</h2>
</div>

<div class="designer">
<h3>
designer
</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your help, this is getting closer to what I want.. however how would I change it so that it isn't so jumpy? For example, after they bounce off each other, they just continuously move in another direction.

Comment: I tried to simulate the animate function with hardcoded random number (adding and subtracting 20 top and left from the collision position). please edit the code block inside setInterval() to get more smoothly animation and desired output.